# Custom thread-safe shared/weak pointer implementation in C++98

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am pretty sure the CppCoreGuidelines say that you should disregard standard libraries and write your own.  Not sure I remember where, probably [P.13](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p13-use-support-libraries-as-appropriate) or somewhere around there...

Anyway here is my implementation:

```
#ifndef SMART_POINTER_HEADER
#define SMART_POINTER_HEADER

#include <cstddef>
#include "mutex.hpp"

namespace my_experimental
{

struct ref_count_data
{
    unsigned int weak_count;
    unsigned int use_count;
};

class reference_count
{
    public:
        reference_count()
        {
            ref_counts.weak_count = 1;
            ref_counts.use_count = 0;
        }

        void add_shared_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.use_count++;
        }

        ref_count_data release_shared_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.use_count--;

            if( !ref_counts.use_count )
            {
                ref_counts.weak_count--;
            }

            return ref_counts;
        }

        void add_weak_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.weak_count++;
        }

        ref_count_data release_weak_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.weak_count--;
            return ref_counts;
        }

        unsigned int get_use_count() const
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            return ref_counts.use_count;
        }

    private:
        mutable mutex ref_count_mutex;
        ref_count_data ref_counts;
};

template < typename T > class shared_pointer
{
    public:
        shared_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        shared_pointer( T* pvalue ) : pdata( pvalue ), rc( NULL )
        {
            rc = new reference_count();
            rc->add_shared_ref();
        }

        //Copy constructor for dynamic_pointer_cast and weak_pointer lock
        shared_pointer( T* pvalue_arg, reference_count * rc_arg ) : pdata( pvalue_arg ), rc( rc_arg )
        {
            if ( NULL == pdata )
            {
                rc = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                rc->add_shared_ref();
            }
        }

        //Copy constructor
        shared_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( sp.pdata ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                rc->add_shared_ref();
            }
        }

        ~shared_pointer()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_shared_ref();

                if ( !updated_counts.use_count )
                {
                    delete pdata;
                }

                if( !updated_counts.weak_count )
                {
                    delete rc;
                }
            }
        }

        T& operator* () const
        {
            return *pdata;
        }

        T* operator-> () const
        {
            return pdata;
        }

        shared_pointer<T>& operator = ( const shared_pointer<T>& sp )
        {
            if ( this != &sp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_shared_ref();

                    if ( !updated_counts.use_count )
                    {
                        delete pdata;
                    }

                    if( !updated_counts.weak_count )
                    {
                        delete rc;
                    }
                }

                pdata = sp.pdata;
                rc = sp.rc;

                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    rc->add_shared_ref();
                }
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool operator !() const
        {
            return !pdata;
        }

        bool operator == ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator == ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other );
        }

        bool operator != ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator != ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other );
        }

        template <class Y, class Z> friend shared_pointer<Y> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<Z>& sp );
        template < class Y > friend class weak_pointer;

    private:
        T* pdata;            // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count
};

template < typename T > class weak_pointer
{
    public:
        weak_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        weak_pointer( const weak_pointer<T>& wp ) : pdata( wp.pdata ), rc( wp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                rc->add_weak_ref();
            }
        }

        weak_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( sp.pdata ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                rc->add_weak_ref();
            }
        }

        ~weak_pointer()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_weak_ref();

                if( !updated_counts.weak_count )
                {
                    delete rc;
                }
            }
        }

        weak_pointer<T>& operator = ( const weak_pointer<T>& wp )
        {
            if ( this != &wp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_weak_ref();

                    if( !updated_counts.weak_count )
                    {
                        delete rc;
                    }
                }

                pdata = wp.pdata;
                rc = wp.rc;

                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    rc->add_weak_ref();
                }
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool expired() const
        {
            if( NULL == rc )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if( 0 == rc->get_use_count() )
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        int use_count() const
        {
            if( NULL == rc )
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return rc->get_use_count();
            }
        }

        shared_pointer<T> lock() const
        {
            if( expired() )
            {
                return shared_pointer<T>( NULL );
            }
            else
            {
                return shared_pointer<T>( pdata, rc );
            }
        }

    private:
        T* pdata;       // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count
};


template <class T, class U> shared_pointer<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<U>& sp )
{
    return shared_pointer<T>( dynamic_cast<T*>( sp.pdata ), sp.rc );
}
}//namespace my_experimental

#endif
```

And here is the contents of mutex.hpp in case you want to compile this code (I use gcc in Linux but should be easy to adapt):

```
#ifndef MUTEX_HEADER
#define MUTEX_HEADER

#include <pthread.h>

namespace my_experimental
{

class mutex
{
    public:
        mutex() { pthread_mutex_init( &pthread_mutex, NULL ); }
        ~mutex() { pthread_mutex_destroy( &pthread_mutex ); }
        int lock() { return pthread_mutex_lock( &pthread_mutex ); }
        int try_lock() { return pthread_mutex_trylock( &pthread_mutex ); }
        int unlock() { return pthread_mutex_unlock( &pthread_mutex ); }

    private:
        pthread_mutex_t pthread_mutex;

        //disallow
        mutex( const mutex& );
        mutex& operator=( mutex const& );
};

template< class Mutex > class lock_guard
{
    public:
        lock_guard( Mutex& mutex_to_lock ) : locked_mutex( mutex_to_lock )
        {
            locked_mutex.lock();
        }

        ~lock_guard() { locked_mutex.unlock(); }

    private:
        Mutex& locked_mutex;

        //disallow
        lock_guard();
        lock_guard( const lock_guard& );
        lock_guard& operator=( lock_guard const& );
};

} //namespace my_experimental

#endif
```

Seems to work fairly well.  I do wonder if there is any way to better handle the synchronization of the reference_count object.

Before I added support for weak pointer I used  `__sync_add_and_fetch` and  `__sync_sub_and_fetch` to make the ref count atomic, however once I introduced multiple ref counts that was no longer sufficient to ensure synchronization.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing much to say about `mutex`. Simple wrapper, straight and to the point. Very neatly written.

Now to what I consider glaring issues

1. `reference_count::release_shared_ref()` is touching `weak_count`. Calling `add_shared_ref` doesn't increment `weak_count`, so neither should `release_shared_ref` decrement it. It seems like a manufactured problem for a mutex.
2. You have a data race in `weak_ptr::lock()`. It's all in the branch here.

   ```
   if( expired() )
   {
       return shared_pointer<T>( NULL );
   }
   else
   {
       return shared_pointer<T>( pdata, rc );
   }
   ```

   Even if `expired()` is done atomically, there can be a context switch right as the `else` branch is entered. During that context switch, `pdata` and `rc` may be destroyed as the last shared pointer dies. So you return a `shared_ptr` which you initialized from two invalid addresses.

Comment: 1. I am deriving this methodology from boost.  In boost the weak count is always the number of weak pointer + ( use_count != 0 ).   Maybe I should adjust the function names (I am open to suggestions).

Comment: 2. I agree this is a race condition and I have been pondering how best to fix it.  I could lock the reference mutex directly from the weak pointer lock function , a bit dirty but should work.   Have any better ideas?

Comment: @NathanOwen - That maybe for boost, but I don't see the major need for it in your own implementation. I *could* have missed something, so IDK. Regarding the data race, why not just query `rc` about the proper pointers? Then initialize the return of `lock` from those queried values.

Comment: I think it may originally have been to allow for atomic logic, not sure.  I suppose I don't really need to do that, but the logic is slightly simpler, at least in the case of week pointer (arguably less clear though).  I would perhaps also argue that it is nice to have the lifetime of pdata controlled solely by use_count and the lifetime of rc being controlled solely by weak_count.  Come to think about it, I might be able to get away with using synchronous increment/decrement builtin atomic operators using this logic. I'll ponder it some more in the morning.

Comment: ...As for storing the pdata pointer in rc, I belive that might introduce a fair amount of overhead.  Since the '->' operator is going to be, by far, the most frequently called function (for typical programs) that operation should have as few instructions as possible.  I could store a copy of the pdata pointer in rc though... Will need to give it some more thought.

Comment: @NathanOwen - Not storing, querying. You can pass `pdata` in, and see if it spits back `nullptr` or `pdata` unmodified.

Comment: All right, I have implemented another implementation based on your feedback.   Let me know what you think :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have edited my solution based on StoryTeller's feedback.  I don't love this implementation, since it relies on public data members, but I believe it is thread safe now, and that is more important.

```
#ifndef SMART_POINTER_HEADER
#define SMART_POINTER_HEADER

#include <cstddef>
#include "mutex.hpp"

namespace my_experimental
{

class reference_count
{
    public:
        unsigned int weak_count;
        unsigned int use_count;
        mutable mutex ref_count_mutex;

        reference_count() : weak_count( 1 ), use_count( 0 ) {}
};

template < typename T > class shared_pointer
{
    public:
        shared_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        shared_pointer( T* pvalue ) : pdata( pvalue ), rc( NULL )
        {
            if( NULL != pvalue )
            {
                rc = new reference_count();
                increment_reference_count();
            }
        }

        //Copy constructor
        shared_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( sp.pdata ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            increment_reference_count();
        }

        ~shared_pointer()
        {
            decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed();
        }

        T& operator* () const
        {
            return *pdata;
        }

        T* operator-> () const
        {
            return pdata;
        }

        shared_pointer<T>& operator = ( const shared_pointer<T>& sp )
        {
            if ( this != &sp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed();

                pdata = sp.pdata;
                rc = sp.rc;

                increment_reference_count();
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool operator !() const
        {
            return !pdata;
        }

        bool operator == ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator == ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other );
        }

        bool operator != ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator != ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other );
        }

        template <class Y, class Z> friend shared_pointer<Y> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<Z>& sp );
        template < class Y > friend class weak_pointer;

    private:
        T* pdata;            // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count

        //Copy constructor for dynamic pointer casting
        shared_pointer( T* pvalue_arg, reference_count * rc_arg ) : pdata( pvalue_arg ), rc( rc_arg )
        {
            if ( NULL == pdata )
            {
                rc = NULL; //just set to NULL
            }
            else
            {
                increment_reference_count();
            }
        }

        void increment_reference_count()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );
                rc->use_count++;
            }
        }

        void decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                bool delete_pdata = false;
                bool delete_rc = false;

                { //lock
                    lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );

                    rc->use_count--;

                    if ( 0 == rc->use_count )
                    {
                        rc->weak_count--;
                        delete_pdata = true;
                    }

                    if( 0 == rc->weak_count )
                    {
                        delete_rc = true;
                    }
                } //unlock

                if( delete_pdata )
                {
                    //best not to call unknown code from locked context so delete here
                    //for example the destructor could end up doing something with a
                    //weak_pointer to pdata (that would be poorly written code but we know nothing
                    //about the destructor we are calling so best not to call from locked context)
                    delete pdata;
                }

                if( delete_rc )
                {
                    //rc contains the mutex that we were locking so we must delete outside of locked context
                    //this is safe as we know that no one else holds a reference to rc once we get here
                    delete rc;
                }
            }
        }
};

template < typename T > class weak_pointer
{
    public:
        weak_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        weak_pointer( const weak_pointer<T>& wp ) : pdata( wp.pdata ), rc( wp.rc )
        {
            increment_reference_count();
        }

        weak_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( sp.pdata ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            increment_reference_count();
        }

        ~weak_pointer()
        {
            decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed();
        }

        weak_pointer<T>& operator = ( const weak_pointer<T>& wp )
        {
            if ( this != &wp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed();

                pdata = wp.pdata;
                rc = wp.rc;

                increment_reference_count();
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool expired() const
        {
            if( NULL == rc )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );

                if( 0 == rc->use_count )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        int use_count() const
        {
            if( NULL == rc )
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );
                return rc->use_count;
            }
        }

        shared_pointer<T> lock() const
        {
            if( NULL == rc )
            {
                return shared_pointer<T>( NULL );
            }
            else
            {
                //create an empty shared pointer and manually assign values
                //once inside locked context.  We cannot return from within
                //locked context as the return will call the copy constructor,
                //which will in turn lock the ref_count_mutex resulting in a
                //deadlock if we are still in locked context
                shared_pointer<T> new_sp;

                {//lock
                    lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );

                    if( 0 == rc->use_count )
                    {
                        return new_sp;
                    }

                    new_sp.rc = rc;
                    new_sp.pdata = pdata;

                    rc->use_count++;
                }//unlock

                return new_sp;
            }
        }

    private:
        T* pdata;            // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count

        void increment_reference_count()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );
                rc->weak_count++;
            }
        }

        void decrement_reference_count_and_delete_if_needed()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                bool delete_rc = false;

                { //lock
                    lock_guard< mutex > rc_lock( rc->ref_count_mutex );

                    rc->weak_count--;

                    if( 0 == rc->weak_count )
                    {
                        delete_rc = true;
                    }
                } //unlock

                if( delete_rc )
                {
                    //rc contains the mutex that we were locking so we must delete outside of locked context
                    //this is safe as we know that no one else holds a reference to rc once we get here
                    delete rc;
                }
            }
        }
};


template <class T, class U> shared_pointer<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<U>& sp )
{
    return shared_pointer<T>( dynamic_cast<T*>( sp.pdata ), sp.rc );
}

}//namespace my_experimental

#endif
```

I look forward to your feedback :-)

Comment: If you want feedback then you should create a new question.

Comment: Might have liked feedback back in 2018, fortunately I am no longer restricted to C++98 and as such no longer need to implement my own unique_ptr.  Now days I would just read the standard, but back then I was just getting started in C++ and knew basically nothing...  Brings back memories.  Recently joined WG21 but still have a lot to learn...

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another variant based on StoryTeller's feedback.  This variant removes the public data members which better protects the locking mechanisms.  It also makes the use_count and weak_count independent, unlike boost's implementation.  Not sure how it compares performance-wise to my previous implementation, will need to run some benchmarks and look into the resulting assembly code.

```
#ifndef SMART_POINTER_HEADER
#define SMART_POINTER_HEADER

#include <cstddef>
#include "mutex.hpp"

namespace my_experimental
{

struct ref_count_data
{
    unsigned int weak_count;
    unsigned int use_count;
};

class reference_count
{
    public:
        reference_count()
        {
            ref_counts.weak_count = 0;
            ref_counts.use_count = 1;
        }

        void * get_shared_ref( void * pdata )
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );

            if ( ref_counts.use_count )
            {
                ref_counts.use_count++;
                return pdata;
            }
            else
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        ref_count_data release_shared_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.use_count--;
            return ref_counts;
        }

        void add_weak_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.weak_count++;
        }

        ref_count_data release_weak_ref()
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            ref_counts.weak_count--;
            return ref_counts;
        }

        unsigned int get_use_count() const
        {
            lock_guard< mutex > lock( ref_count_mutex );
            return ref_counts.use_count;
        }

    private:
        mutable mutex ref_count_mutex;
        ref_count_data ref_counts;
};

template < typename T > class shared_pointer
{
    public:
        shared_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        shared_pointer( T* pvalue ) : pdata( pvalue ), rc( NULL )
        {
            if ( NULL != pdata )
            {
                rc = new reference_count();
            }
        }

        //Copy constructor
        shared_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( NULL ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                pdata = static_cast<T*>( rc->get_shared_ref( sp.pdata ) );

                if ( NULL == pdata )
                {
                    rc = NULL;
                }
            }
        }

        ~shared_pointer()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_shared_ref();

                if ( 0 == updated_counts.use_count )
                {
                    delete pdata;

                    if ( 0 == updated_counts.weak_count )
                    {
                        delete rc;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        T& operator* () const
        {
            return *pdata;
        }

        T* operator-> () const
        {
            return pdata;
        }

        shared_pointer<T>& operator = ( const shared_pointer<T>& sp )
        {
            if ( this != &sp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_shared_ref();

                    if ( 0 == updated_counts.use_count )
                    {
                        delete pdata;

                        if ( 0 == updated_counts.weak_count )
                        {
                            delete rc;
                        }
                    }
                }

                pdata = NULL;
                rc = sp.rc;

                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    pdata = static_cast<T*>( rc->get_shared_ref( sp.pdata ) );

                    if ( NULL == pdata )
                    {
                        rc = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool operator !() const
        {
            return !pdata;
        }

        bool operator == ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator == ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata == other );
        }

        bool operator != ( const shared_pointer<T>& other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other.pdata );
        }

        bool operator != ( void * other ) const
        {
            return ( pdata != other );
        }

        template <class Y, class Z> friend shared_pointer<Y> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<Z>& sp );
        template < class Y > friend class weak_pointer;

    private:
        T* pdata;            // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count

        //Copy constructor for dynamic_pointer_cast and weak_pointer lock
        shared_pointer( T* pvalue_arg, reference_count * rc_arg ) : pdata( NULL ), rc( rc_arg )
        {
            if ( NULL == pvalue_arg )
            {
                rc = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                pdata = static_cast<T*>( rc->get_shared_ref( pvalue_arg ) );

                if ( NULL == pdata )
                {
                    rc = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
};

template < typename T > class weak_pointer
{
    public:
        weak_pointer() : pdata( NULL ), rc( NULL ) {} //default constructor

        weak_pointer( const weak_pointer<T>& wp ) : pdata( wp.pdata ), rc( wp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                rc->add_weak_ref();
            }
        }

        weak_pointer( const shared_pointer<T>& sp ) : pdata( sp.pdata ), rc( sp.rc )
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                rc->add_weak_ref();
            }
        }

        ~weak_pointer()
        {
            if ( NULL != rc )
            {
                ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_weak_ref();

                if ( ( 0 == updated_counts.use_count ) && ( 0 == updated_counts.weak_count ) )
                {
                    delete rc;
                }
            }
        }

        weak_pointer<T>& operator = ( const weak_pointer<T>& wp )
        {
            if ( this != &wp ) // Avoid self assignment
            {
                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    ref_count_data updated_counts = rc->release_weak_ref();

                    if ( ( 0 == updated_counts.use_count ) && ( 0 == updated_counts.weak_count ) )
                    {
                        delete rc;
                    }
                }

                pdata = wp.pdata;
                rc = wp.rc;

                if ( NULL != rc )
                {
                    rc->add_weak_ref();
                }
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool expired() const
        {
            if ( NULL == rc )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( 0 == rc->get_use_count() )
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        int use_count() const
        {
            if ( NULL == rc )
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return rc->get_use_count();
            }
        }

        shared_pointer<T> lock() const
        {
            return shared_pointer<T>( pdata, rc ); //this will return a NULL shared_pointer if expired
        }

    private:
        T* pdata;            // pointer
        reference_count* rc; // Reference count
};

template <class T, class U> shared_pointer<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( const shared_pointer<U>& sp )
{
    return shared_pointer<T>( dynamic_cast<T*>( sp.pdata ), sp.rc );
}

}//namespace my_experimental

#endif
```